# How to disable or remove a default error from angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS.

When I open the developer Tools on Chrome, even official tutorial has an error like below.

**Official Tutorial**

http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-12/app/#/phones

**Error Message on Chrome**

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module phonecatApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'phonecatApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that yo......0)

And somehow in terms of feature, it just works fine.

But I want to remove this error.

Could someone show me how to remove this error?

Thanks,

Comment: I do not see that error. (Chrome)

Comment: I don't see it either (Chrome)

Comment: Thanks! After removing all extensions and clear Browsing Data, this error disappeared.So my Chrome should have been the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's some time happened with the version on angularJS you are using in, like e.g. using cdn for angulasJS gives you spontaneously this error.
So best option is to use one stable version not the new one's. 
stable versions : angulasJS 1.2.0 and 1.2.1
these are somewhat unstable versions 1.2.10 and 1.2.11